# MongoDB\Driver\Manager php insert array json object

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

This is my simple Php.

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
```

I have this Array Json in a variable `$obj = file_get_contents("link google api")`
https://pastebin.com/zPA1r0Vs

Exist a way to save directly $obj in mongodb withoud a foreach?

```
$bulk->insert($obj);     (this is line 9)
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.invoicing', $bulk);    (this is line 10)
```

this is error:

```
Warning: MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite::insert() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /var/www/html/php/php_info.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Cannot do an empty bulk write in /var/www/html/php/php_info.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/php/php_info.php(10): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->executeBulkWrite('db.invoicing', Object(MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/php/php_info.php on line 10
```

Comment: The JSON in your pastebin is not an array. The property `predictions` in $obj is though. Try using that in the first parameter for insert

Comment: Worthy of note here is that you are "using the wrong driver". The code here is the "low level" interface whose intended audience is for authors of other "higher level" driver implementations. The package you "should" be using is the [PHPLIB driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/), which actually namespaces these methods to the [`Collection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/class/MongoDBCollection/).

Comment: This is also echoed on the [entry page for the low level driver](http://php.net/mongodb) you are currently using. *"Application developers should consider using this extension in conjunction with the » MongoDB PHP library, which implements the same higher level APIs found in MongoDB drivers for other languages."*. There is also a general [overview on "which is used for what" on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php). Switch your driver and use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-bulkWrite/) like you are supposed to

Comment: @NeilLunn your link PHPLIB send to mongodb site. Here they talk about

-PHP legacy driver => http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php
-LOW level driver (which I use) => https://secure.php.net/mongodb

PhpLegacy driver use new MongoClient(), but on every page they write

"Warning This extension is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used."
MongoDB extensione link to Low Level Driver. Where you find Collection link?

Thanks for ur reply

Comment: @AndrewLohr yes, sorry, I write wrong. Predictions is the array with max 5 slot

Comment: @NeilLunn I try use this https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#insert-documents but $collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->db->invoicing; give me error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found. I use pecl to install mongodb. Composer is different?

Comment: Told you before, you have the wrong library. The PHPLIB driver can be installed without composer, but it's probably easier to install with. Plenty of material on installing composer bundled packages without composer if that's your problem. Very clear instructions in the documentation I linked you to as well. It's not the "legacy driver" it's the "new one". Much as the direct examples to the correct classes and methods I gave you show. You are clearly confused and that is why I corrected you. So install the right thing.

Comment: @NeilLunn I think that library on pecl is maybe different? I see that on the mongodb page pecl for php was not mentioned. [Php Library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/install-php-library/) . On pecl the UNIQUE version is mongodb (mongo was deprecated), so I could not have install a "wrong" package no? I try to install with composer and `$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->db->invoicing;` work very well. Thanks for support